# Replacing a space between 2 numbers(not text) with a comma

Tags: java, regex, text, replace

Have a text file coming in for clean up, and I need to replace the "spaces" with commas, only if it's between two numbers.

```
1130 11/23/14
UP AIR TEMP 122.81 LO AIR TEMP 117.75 SOURCE TEMP 102.76 RCVR TEMP 113.03
```

to

```
1130,11/23/14
UP AIR TEMP,122.81,LO AIR TEMP,117.75,SOURCE TEMP,102.76,RCVR TEMP,113.03
```

Note the spaces between letters are not replaced.

I am using

```
line = line.replaceAll(" {2,}", ",");
```

to get rid of all the spaces greater than 1, just can't figure out how to do the dates.

Comment: you mean `before` 2 numbers?

Comment: It looks like your example also replaces the spaces between a letter and a number, ie. `TEMP,122` ... Was that your intention?

Comment: i mean any time there is 2 NUMBERS seperated by a space.
the only line i need this to affect is the date line, i can get the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Regex

**EDIT:** (As per the comments)

From you code example you need this:

```
line = line.replaceAll("(?<=\\d) +(?=\\d)", ",");
```

That is replace 1 or more spaces by comma **only if it is preceded and followed by a digit**.